# Removing Breaks Before H1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that is like this:

```
<div id="contBody">
    <br />
    <br />
    <!-- Maybe more, it's a variable number of <br /> that can appear -->
    <h1 id="header">Test</h1>
</div>
```

Since the number of `<br />` before the `<h1>` varies I and I want to remove them programmatically, how I can do it using jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove all of them before the h1 elements, do this:

```
$('br + h1').prevAll('br').remove();
```

Using the [`next-adjacent-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/), this will find all `<h1>` elements that are preceded by at least once `<br>` element.

Then it uses the [`prevAll()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) method to select the previous `<br>` elements, and the [`remove()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method to remove them.

Comment: Keep in mind the `br + h1` is a more expensive (non-native) selector, and doesn't add much benefit, it's quicker to just do the `.prevAll()` from the known nodes found using native runnable selectors.  Also, this requires the `<br>` be *immediately* before the `<h1>`, not sure if that's the case.

Comment: @Nick: `br + h1` is a native selector for `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @Nick: It also could be that any `<h1> elements that don't have an adjacent `<br>` before it should be avoided. The question seems to indicate that there's more than one `<h1>` to target, and the `<br>` elements are adjacent.

Comment: not in all versions of jQuery, whereas going ogg `h1` or `#header` works all the way back.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, the OP will have to chime in, since `id="header"` is pretty specific he may be looking at a single use, in which case `$('#header')` is *much* faster and safer.

Comment: @Nick: Could be. More info would be good. And the `next-adjacent-selector` arrived in jQuery version 1 [according to the docs](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/). Unless you're talking about `qsa` support, then yes true.

Comment: ...anyway, I really don't think jQuery v1 support is a reasonable standard unless specifically requested.

Comment: I meant the qsa piece...hence the native vs not comment :)

Comment: This answer is epic. Great solution.

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, I figured that, so I updated my comment a little late.

Answer (score 4):

You can find them all with [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) them, like this:

```
$("#header").prevAll("br").remove();
```